# Regex multiple group and match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I want to know if what I have in mind is possible with regex expression.

Here the string :
[#hall: hall] de [#immeuble: immeuble] [#hall: est équipé] d'une installation liée aux logements qu'[#hall: il dessert]

I would like to match everything that have [#hall: xxx ] or [#immeuble: xxx ] (or #else:). For now, I achieved to have :

- hall
- est équipé
- il dessert

With that expression : [#hall: (.*?)]

I want to know if it's possible to have :

- hall
- immeuble
- est
- équipé
- il
- dessert

And is it possible to have the match information ? Like :

- hall : #hall
- immeuble : #immeuble
- est : #hall
- équipé : #hall
- il : #hall
- dessert : #hall

Thanks for your help

Edit : I achieve to have some information about the hashtag part with this regex :

```
\[(?<trigger>.*?): (?<result>.*?)\]
```

Comment: Maybe this regex can help a bit: `(#\w+):(\s[\wàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñ]+)*` I didn't manage to match all words behind the `:` in single matches, but I have the feeling there is not much missing to the regex...
I recommend you to develop the regex under the following link: https://regex101.com/r/e6EGSv/1 It also provides explanations and you can see all the matches and groups.

Comment: Which language/regex flavor are you using? This is easy to solve with variable-length lookbehind assertions, but only a few regex flavors support those.

Answer (score 0):

With a regex engine that supports indeterminate-length lookbehind (like .NET), it's easy:

```
(?<=         # Assert that it's possible to match this before the current position:
  \[         # a square bracket
  (          # followed by (start capturing group 1, so we can reference this later)
    \#       # a hash character
    [^][:]+  # and one or more characters except colon or square brackets
  )          # End of capturing group
  :          # followed by a colon
  [^][]*     # and any number of characters except square brackets
)            # End of lookbehind assertion
\b           # Assert that we start the match at a word boundary
(\w+)        # Match an alphanumeric word and capture it in group 2
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3hMsjx/1).

In a single line:

```
(?<=\[(#[^][:]+):[^][]*)\b(\w+)
```

In JavaScript (code snippet generated with help from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com):

```
var myregexp = /(?<=\[(#[^][:]+):[^][]*)\b(\w+)/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    console.log("Trigger is : " + match[1] + ". Clause is : " + match[2] + '. <br/>');
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

Comment: Seems very good ! But I don't achieve to loop through groups :/
I tried with :
                let regexp = /(?<=\[(?<trigger>\#[^][:]+):[^][]*)\b(?<result> \w +)/gi;
                const group = clause.matchAll(regexp);
                for (const element of group) {
                    let {
                        trigger,
                        result
                    } = element.groups;
                    console.log("Trigger is : " + trigger + ". Clause is : " + result + '. <br/>');
                  }
But I didn't have anything on console. No errors, no results.

Comment: Which language is that?

Comment: It’s in Javascript

Comment: Most browser implementations should by now support lookbehind, so as long as you're not targeting IE, this should work (see code example).

Comment: It's in a word addin, so it normally use edge :/

Comment: Edge should work too, but Word has its own, nonstandard regex implementation. If the addin uses the desktop regex engine, you're severely limited. That's why I asked right at the very beginning to specify which regex engine you're targeting...

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to use JavaScript, you can use 2 capture groups, and then after process the group values to get the desired results:

```
\[(#[^\][:]+):\s*([^\][]*?)\s*]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `#[^\][:]+` Match `#` followed by any char except `[` `]` `:`
- `)` Close group 1
- `:\s*` Match `:` followed by optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\][]*?`
- `)` Close group 2
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `]` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7VWdN/1)

```js
const regex = /\[(#[^\][:]+):\s*([^\][]*?)\s*]/g;
const str = `[#hall: hall] de [#immeuble: immeuble] [#hall: est équipé] d'une installation liée aux logements qu'[#hall: il dessert]`;

let singleWords = [];
let composed = [];

let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  const parts = m[2].split(/\s+/);
  singleWords = singleWords.concat(parts);
  composed = composed.concat(parts.map(v => `${v} : ${m[1]}`))
}
console.log(singleWords);
console.log(composed);
```

Or you could create all the matches first in one array:

```js
const s = `[#hall: hall] de [#immeuble: immeuble] [#hall: est équipé] d'une installation liée aux logements qu'[#hall: il dessert]`;
const regex = /\[(#[^\][:]+):\s*([^\][]*?)\s*]/g;
const result = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2].split(/\s+/)]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for oyr answer.
Same problem like the other answer, I don't achieve to have matches with javascript :/

Comment: @Furya Where are you running the javascript?

Comment: Visual studio 2022, it's an addin for word.

Comment: @Furya So in that plugin you use JavaScript to get the matches? Or do you only enter a regex somewhere?

Comment: It's a plugin that we write in html + css + js so I use js to get the matches. It's a .js file.

Comment: @Furya I have updated the answer with a JavaScript example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following.

```
#(?<trigger>hall|immeuble|est|équipé|il|dessert): (?<result>[^\]]*)
```

Output

```
hall, hall
immeuble, immeuble
hall, est équipé
hall, il dessert
```